# how to avoid nginx to replace %20 by whitespace when using as a proxy (proxy_pass) ?

Tags: nginx

I am using a nginx as a proxy for an apache server.

Here is my config:

```
location ~ ^/subsite/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/subsite/$1?$query_string;
    }
```

the problem is that if I send a request with %20 like mywebsite.com/subsite/variable/value/title/Access%20denied/another/example

the %20 is replaced by a whitespace, and apache don't care about all the end of the request after Access /title/Access

Any Idea ?

Comment: I found that the issue is linked with the (.*) and the $1, this replace %20 to whitespace with just a proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1; this is working

Comment: As soon as you are able, you can/should answer/accept your own question so others will know that there is a solution. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: In my case, I had error 505 (Unrecognized HTTP version: ' HTTP/1.0') from .Net Core. The solution below fixed it.

Answer (score 42):

I was able to solve a similar issue -- we have an api that requires the search terms to be part of the URL path. Passing the output directly to the proxy_pass directive caused it to throw a 502 even though the request was properly url encoded.

Here's the solution we came up with:

```
location ~ /api/search(/.*) {
        set $query $1;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3003$query;

    }
```

The "set" directive seems to keep the url encoding intact (or re-encodes from what the regex is passing back in $1).

Comment: Thanks, this save my day. I wonder if nginx doc mentioned this.

Comment: Coming in here about three years later - this is the trick that solved my issue. Thank you!  I would like though to understand why this is needed...