# nginx gives 400 bad request for urls with whitespace

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have nginx proxying requests to a node.js web app in the backend on a Ubuntu box. For requests to api.example.com with whitespace in the url get a 400 bad request error. Think the problem line of code is:

```
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002$uri$is_args$query_string;
```

however not sure how to rewrite it.

This is how the site configuration at /etc/nginx/sites-available/default looks:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002$uri$is_args$query_string;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
```

Comment: You should try: `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002;`

Comment: I also need the query string to persist.

Comment: proxy_pass forwards all the things after the hostname

Comment: unless am missing something `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002;` was not passing along the querystrings hence had to resort to explicitly rewriting the uri to include the querystring.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to avoid nginx to replace %20 by whitespace when using as a proxy (proxy\_pass) ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838905/how-to-avoid-nginx-to-replace-20-by-whitespace-when-using-as-a-proxy-proxy-pas)